# What does the `'` mean in english word

Tags: literature

I am kind stuck when reading a sonnet:

> That time of year thou mayst in me behold
> When yellow leaves, or none, or few, do hang
> Upon those boughs which shake against the cold,
> Bare ruin'd choirs, where late the sweet birds sang.
> In me thou see'st the twilight of such day
> As after sunset fadeth in the west;
> Which by and by black night doth take away,
> Death's second self, that seals up all in rest.
> In me thou see'st the glowing of such fire,
> That on the ashes of his youth doth lie,
> As the death-bed, whereon it must expire,
> Consum'd with that which it was nourish'd by.
> This thou perceiv'st, which makes thy love more strong,
> To love that well, which thou must leave ere long.

There are several words that are very weird.

Example :  Consum'd, perceiv'st, see'st.

I try to search online and find that they are equal to the same word without the `'`,

so I am wondering why we have the `'` and when we see the english word with `'`, will the same rule apply? (removing the `'`)

Thank you so much

Comment: It's another way of spelling the letter "e" in old texts. More specifically, of spelling the vowel /ə/, or the schwa, which is often so subtle it barely feels like a vowel. "'d" or "ed" for the past tense, and "'st" or "est" for the second person present tense ("thou")

Comment: *Consum'd, perceiv'st* are not the same as the word without the apostrophe - there is no word *consumd* or *perceivst*.

Comment: This is a reasonable question to ask but it is such a  basic matter that it belongs on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aforementioned sonnet is Shakespeare's Sonnet 73, most likely written [in the 1590s](https://www.litcharts.com/poetry/william-shakespeare/sonnet-73-that-time-of-year-thou-mayst-in-me-behold); this goes a long way towards explaining the apostrophe. This is because in the early 16th century (16th century being 1501-1600), [the apostrophe was used to indicated omitted letters in a word](https://blog.oup.com/2017/05/apostrophes-language-writing/); and Shakespeare, being a writer in that period, often used these omissions in his texts - some examples being 'tis, 'twill, and 'twas.

However, these apostrophes were not only to indicate omission; in some cases, it was used to indicate where pronunciation was not needed instead. An example being the usage of "wand'ring" in Shakespeare's work - the omission isn't simply to write one less "e", instead it serves as an indicator for then-actors (who would read and act out Shakespeare's work) to pronounce the word "wandering" as wand-ring instead of wan-der-ing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, as people mentioned in the chat? I could just understand the `'` as another version for e? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the apostrophe in fact commonly substitutes for vowels, not just e, in texts from that period; and it directs pronunciation as well.

Comment: A sonnet isn't for acting, but it _does_ have a set number of syllables (10) per line. The apostrophe indicates that 'seest' should be pronounced as one syllable, not the more usual 'see-est'. People in Shakespeare's time may have pronounced the '-ed' on the end of words like 'consumed'. Of course we still use an apostrophe to indicate an omitted letter, as in _don't_, _he's_ etc.

Comment: Well observed that sonnets weren't to be acted out back then. I'll change the answer for clarity's sake later.